# How to get the count of spaces before the string starts

Tags: coldfusion

How do you get the number of spaces before a string starts in ColdFusion?

I mean, I have a string like this "   Hello World!"

I want to get the count of spaces (in this case 3) before the word "Hello" starts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with ColdFusion but considering [this API](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions-pt0_18.html) you should be able to get the result you want with:

```
Len(str) - Len(LTrim(str))
```

But maybe there is a better solution :)

Comment: You could also try something like `REFind("\S", str)`. Might be more efficient for large strings.

Comment: Faster than the regex flavoured version too, naturally

Comment: Note that ltrim (and its brethren) removes all kinds of whitespace characters, not just spaces (#CHR(32)#). If you have carriage returns, tabs, or other control characters in there this will give you a false result.